# File system activity history tool?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, disk-space

My home PC (Win 7) fills up drive C, either by itself or as a result of something I do or use. I don't download, I keep track of my clouds sync, but GBs of free space mysteriously disappear (about 20 GB a month). I only have 30 GB left with not much I can delete at the moment. Sure there are backup solutions, but it's not really a solution.

So far I checked the Windows Update downloads (not much there), Chrome cache, tmp etc. (I run cleanup every week, which clears a few MB here and there).

Does anyone know a tool that can show the source of the problem? For example, showing a graph of free space over time and history of the files adding/growing and when?

I currently use WinDirStat which shows the files tree and filesize map, pretty useful for clearing space but unhelpful in understanding what grows over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The product [TreeSize Professional](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/) has an interesting feature to track down increases of used disk space: It has the ability to [compare the current state with a previous one and show the differences](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/xml-reports_and_snapshots.shtml). The previous state can either be a scan exported from TreeSize or a Windows shadow copy which Windows e.g. creates along with a system restore point.

[image]

A 30 day fully functional [trial version](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/download.shtml) is available at not cost and without registration. Full disclosure: I am the author of the TreeSize product family.

Comment: I'll try it, thnx.

Comment: The problem was system restore by the way. Great software @joachim-marder!